# Can't boot to alternate OS or Live CD

Tags: boot, google-chrome, chromebook

I'm having trouble installing a new OS on a Toshiba Satellite Chromebook. I continue to encounter a message *"The device you inserted does not contain Chrome OS"*.

I basically followed Chrome OS's [Poking around your Chrome OS Device](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device). The device wiped itself after I enabled developer mode. I can enter developer mode via <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd>, and I get the message *"Boot verification is OFF"* and then I get a message *"Chrome OS is missing or damaged"*. I'm fine with it because I'm installing a new OS.

However, when I insert the thumbdrive with [debian-8.3.0-amd64-lxde.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.3.0/amd64/iso-cd/) ***`dd`***'d on to it, it results in the message *"The device you inserted does not contain Chrome OS"*. I get the same message when I boot with the thumbdrive inserted. I also get the same message when attempt to boot [debian-8.3.0-i386-lxde.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.3.0/amd64/iso-cd/).

According to Product Forums and [Chromebook Central Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/2WTLBi7j1Lg), it could be a problem with the thumbdrive maker or the physical USB port. The forum question states there's a problem with ScanDisk dirves, but I tried both ***PNY*** and generic manufacturer called ***USB2.0*** (according to `dmesg`). The forum post also states there can be problems with USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports. I tried both USB ports with no joy.

I also found a message that says to boot with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (USB boot) and another for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (legacy boot), but neither helped.

Any ideas what the secret recipe is to actually boot to another OS?

---

Below is the output of ***`crossystem --all`***. I believe it was taken with only a USB boot; and not a Legacy boot.

```
arch                   = x86                            # Platform architecture
backup_nvram_request   = 1                              # Backup the nvram somewhere at the next boot. Cleared on success.
block_devmode          = 0                              # Block all use of developer mode
clear_tpm_owner_request = 0                              # Clear TPM owner on next boot
clear_tpm_owner_done   = 1                              # Clear TPM owner done
cros_debug             = 1                              # OS should allow debug features
dbg_reset              = 0                              # Debug reset mode request (writable)
debug_build            = 0                              # OS image built for debug features
dev_boot_usb           = 1                              # Enable developer mode boot from USB/SD (writable)
dev_boot_legacy        = 0                              # Enable developer mode boot Legacy OSes (writable)
dev_boot_signed_only   = 0                              # Enable developer mode boot only from official kernels (writable)
dev_default_boot       = disk                           # default boot from legacy or usb (writable)
devsw_boot             = 1                              # Developer switch position at boot
devsw_cur              = 1                              # Developer switch current position
disable_dev_request    = 0                              # Disable virtual dev-mode on next boot
ecfw_act               = RW                             # Active EC firmware
fmap_base              = 0xffe10000                     # Main firmware flashmap physical address
fwb_tries              = 0                              # Try firmware B count (writable)
fw_vboot2              = 0                              # 1 if firmware was selected by vboot2 or 0 otherwise
fwid                   = Google_Swanky.5216.238.5       # Active firmware ID
fwupdate_tries         = 0                              # Times to try OS firmware update (writable, inside kern_nv)
fw_tried               = A                              # Firmware tried this boot (vboot2)
fw_try_count           = 0                              # Number of times to try fw_try_next (writable)
fw_try_next            = A                              # Firmware to try next (vboot2,writable)
fw_result              = unknown                        # Firmware result this boot (vboot2,writable)
fw_prev_tried          = A                              # Firmware tried on previous boot (vboot2)
fw_prev_result         = unknown                        # Firmware result of previous boot (vboot2)
hwid                   = SWANKY E5A-E3P-A47             # Hardware ID
kern_nv                = 0x00000000                     # Non-volatile field for kernel use
kernkey_vfy            = hash                           # Type of verification done on kernel key block
loc_idx                = 0                              # Localization index for firmware screens (writable)
mainfw_act             = A                              # Active main firmware
mainfw_type            = developer                      # Active main firmware type
nvram_cleared          = 1                              # Have NV settings been lost?  Write 0 to clear
oprom_needed           = 0                              # Should we load the VGA Option ROM at boot?
recovery_reason        = 0                              # Recovery mode reason for current boot
recovery_request       = 0                              # Recovery mode request (writable)
recovery_subcode       = 0                              # Recovery reason subcode (writable)
recoverysw_boot        = 0                              # Recovery switch position at boot
recoverysw_cur         = (error)                        # Recovery switch current position
recoverysw_ec_boot     = 0                              # Recovery switch position at EC boot
ro_fwid                = Google_Swanky.5216.238.5       # Read-only firmware ID
sw_wpsw_boot           = 1                              # Firmware write protect software setting enabled at boot (Baytrail only)
tpm_attack             = 0                              # TPM was interrupted since this flag was cleared
tpm_fwver              = 0x00050001                     # Firmware version stored in TPM
tpm_kernver            = 0x00010001                     # Kernel version stored in TPM
tpm_rebooted           = 0                              # TPM requesting repeated reboot (vboot2)
tried_fwb              = 0                              # Tried firmware B before A this boot
vdat_flags             = 0x00002c54                     # Flags from VbSharedData
vdat_lfdebug           = Check A result=12
Check B result=0
Firmware index booted=0x00
TPM combined version at start=0x00050001
Lowest combined version from firmware=0x00050001
 # LoadFirmware() debug data (not in print-all)
vdat_lkdebug           = Calls to LoadKernel()=1
Call 1:
  Boot flags=0x01
  Boot mode=2
  Test error=0
  Return code=0
  Debug flags=0x00
  Drive sectors=30777344
  Sector size=512
  Check result=4
  Kernel partitions found=1
  Kernel 1:
    GPT index=2
    Start sector=20480
    Sector count=32768
    Combined version=0x00010001
    Check result=19
    Debug flags=0x00
 # LoadKernel() debug data (not in print-all)
vdat_timers            = LFS=190037224,270923042 LF=271933896,415021854 LK=0,30822665 # Timer values from VbSharedData
wipeout_request        = 0                              # Firmware requested factory reset (wipeout)
wpsw_boot              = 1                              # Firmware write protect hardware switch position at boot
wpsw_cur               = 1                              # Firmware write protect hardware switch current position
```

Comment: Do you have OS Verification turned off? just trying to get some more info of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin - I believe OS Verification is off based on messages like *"Boot verification is OFF"* and *`dev_boot_signed_only = 0`*.